# german Umlaute break when form is submitted

Tags: php, post, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

i have a very strange phenomena trying to migrate an older php project from iso-8859-1 to utf-8

when typing a german umlaut like "äöüß" into a textfield an submitting it i receive broken ones like "Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã�"

header is set to

```
<?php header("Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8"); ?>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

the form is set to

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8">
```

and so on - i tried everything i could think of - anybody got an ide or experience with an alike problem?

best regards,
Lupo

Comment: “Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã�” is basically UTF-8 encoded data “äöüß” misinterpreted as windows-1252 encoded. Exactly where (in which program, under which conditions) do you see “Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼Ã�”?

Comment: currently i am testing in a localhost environment with xampp running and using a new chrome version as browser on a windows 8 machine.

Comment: Where do you receive them? If you see them "in your database", (phpmyadmin), you have to change the Encoding of the varchar field you put it into.

Comment: The ß is not really an Umlaut, though its specific to the german language...

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution thats working for my case:

i had to change the accept-charset from UTF-8 back to ISO-8859-15 then the field values look ok again - to be able to process the received data i have to utf8_encode them - seems a bit weird but it works fine now.

Thank you all for your time and Jukka for the help.

best regards, 
Lupo

Comment: The problem is simply that the receiver is not interpreting the characters in the encoding they're actually in. You sent UTF-8 to the server, you output UTF-8 back to the page, but for some reason it was interpreted as ISO-8859. You can confirm this by reverting back to the previous situation and explicitly telling the browser to interpret the data as UTF-8 in the View > Encoding menu. Your fix is not a fix if you actually need to handle UTF-8 (which you should).

Comment: i agree to your explanation but i cannot confirm it since the chars appearance keeps broken when i change the encoding in the browser (which was utf-8 by default in the first place).

Comment: Then you're breaking the characters somewhere along the chain browser → server → browser. We'd need to see the entire code to say where. Maybe this helps in the meantime: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: You can also try calling "SET NAMES UTF8" before making any other queries. See if that helps. we had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you managed to find a solution.
And if you don't want to worry about so many different charset codings or if htmlentities doesn't work for others, here the alternative:
I used mysqli DB connection (and PHPV5)  Form post for writing/inserting to MySQl DB.

```
$Notes = $_POST['Notes']; //can be text input or textarea.


$Notes = str_replace('"', '&quot;', $Notes);  //double quotes for mailto: emails.  
$von = array("ä","ö","ü","ß","Ä","Ö","Ü"," ","é");  //to correct double whitepaces as well
$zu  = array("&auml;","&ouml;","&uuml;","&szlig;","&Auml;","&Ouml;","&Uuml;","&nbsp;","&#233;");  
$Notes = str_replace($von, $zu, $Notes);  
echo " Notes:".$Notes."<br>" ;  
$Notes = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $Notes); //for recommended mysqli DB connection.
//$Notes = mysql_real_escape_string($Notes); //for old deprecated mysql DB connection.

// mysqli_real_escape_string Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

echo " Notes:".$Notes ;  //ready for inserting  
//Optinal:
```

$charset = mysqli_character_set_name($link);  //only works for mysqli DB connection
    printf ("To check your character set but not necessary %s\n",$charset);

Comment: And add this line in the header if funny characters appear.<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">